# Resort LIs in different ULs

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I've been racking my brain around this and can't figure out a solution.  Basically I have sets of ULs and want to reorder all of the LIs in the same structure:

```
<ul>
   <li><span data-sort="-1">-1</span></li>
   <li><span data-sort="10">10</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><span data-sort="4">4</span></li>
   <li><span data-sort="7">7</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><span data-sort="5">5</span></li>
</ul>
```

I want this returned like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><span data-sort="-1">-1</span></li>
   <li><span data-sort="4">4</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><span data-sort="5">5</span></li>
   <li><span data-sort="7">7</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li><span data-sort="10">10</span></li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated in advance.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah the Stack Overflow police have arrived. 
Can you please mark one answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
var uls = $('ul'),
    lis = $('>li', uls);
    ul  = uls.empty().first(),

lis.sort(function(a,b) {
    return parseInt($(a).text(),10) > parseInt($(b).text(), 10);
}).each(function(_,li) {
    ul = ul.find('li').length > 1 ? ul.next() : ul;
    ul.append(li)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BpMp7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach.

I'm guessing you wanted to compare the sort data attribute so I created a sort function that compares their values. It then writes out some custom html and breaks the lists every two LI's. This can be adjusted at the top.

```
function sortMe(a, b) {
    return ($(a).find('span').data("sort") - $(b).find('span').data("sort"));
}

$li.sort(sortMe).each(function (i, el) {
    //every two start a new list
    if (n == numberInEach) {
        str += "</ul><ul>";
        n = 0;
    }
    str += $(el).html();
    n++;
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/9HNAQ/1/embedded/result/)

There are performance enhancements you can make, such as moving the data attribute up a node to the list itself and instead of injecting the full element you could just make an array of the content etc.